# Adding private messaging to a Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop an HTML app with Django using python 3.3.3, and was wondering if there was a simple way to implement a user - to - user private messaging system. I've searched for preexisting apps, but most are out of active development, and other online answers were mostly not useful at all. If possible, I would like it so there are no external dependencies. If there is a simple way to implement this function I would love to know. Thanks.

Comment: Any pre-existing app would _be_ an external dependency. The only way to avoid external dependencies is to implement it yourself. It is not that complex, so the "simple way" is to just to go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll have to roll your own, but really doesn't sound hard.

Is there a reason you'd like to do it in Django? Django is not a simple CMS that you just install and enable some features to make it work. *It's a framework*, which means you'll have to do some things yourself. And doing this yourself, if you're at least a bit proficient, shouldn't be that hard.

Let's say you have a site / an app written in django and want to implement private messages. All you'd need are two models: User and Messages and save your private message to Messages with two foreign keys for sender and reciever.

You'll have to be more specific with your question to get more specific answers.